# Multiple lookups based on users

Tags: powerbi, vlookup, dax, lookup, powerquery

I'm trying to display a list of users who have broken rules in a system.
The data I'm working off is structured like:

```
TABLE_1:   
USER | PRIVILEGE        
 A    |  1  
 A    |  2  
 A    |  3  
 B    |  1  
 B    |  3  
 C    |  2  
 C    |  3  
 C    |  4  

TABLE_2:   
RULE_ID | PRIVILEGE_1 | PRIVILEGE_2       
    1   |       1     |       3     
    2   |       2     |       3
```

The goal is to find users that hold both PRIVILEGE_1 and PRIVILEGE_2 from the TABLE_2 and return them in a new table with the columns "USER" and "RULE_ID" to show which rules they have broken. For example...

```
TABLE_3:   
USER  | RULE_ID
 A    |  1  
 A    |  2  
 B    |  1  
 C    |  2
```

Tried filtering and lookup values but haven't been able to find a solution yet. Any help appreciated!

Comment: can you add to your question a couple of examples of the desired outcome? It's unclear what "broken rules" are.

Comment: @RADO added an example :)

Comment: frankly, I still have no clue what you asking.

Comment: Which language / platform are you trying to use? You've tagged several.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I interpret your request: All "Rules" are composed of two privileges.  Find all users who are associated with both privileges in a rule.

I solved this using Power Query.

I used your sample data (I called Table1 "User" and Table2 "Rule") and created the result table User_Rule.  Here is the final M query from the Advanced Editor.

```
let
    Source = Rule,
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"PRIVILEGE_1"}, User, {"PRIVILEGE"}, "User", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded User" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "User", {"USER"}, {"USER"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded User",{"USER", "RULE_ID", "PRIVILEGE_1", "PRIVILEGE_2"}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Reordered Columns", {"PRIVILEGE_2", "USER"}, User, {"PRIVILEGE", "USER"}, "User", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Queries1",{"PRIVILEGE_1", "PRIVILEGE_2", "User"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

As Applied Steps:

1. Create User_Rule as a reference to Rule

[image]

2. Do a Merge Queries to User on RULE.PRIVELEGE_1 and USER.PRIVILEGE.  Use a left join here.

[image]

3. Expand the 'User' column from the Merged Table

[image]

4. Reorder the columns

[image]

5. Do another merge queries to User.  Notice that this join is on two fields, and it is an inner join, not a left join.  Hold down the [ctrl] key to select more than one field from the merge queries dialog.  Make sure you select the fields in the same order (small numerals 1 and 2 will appear in the column headers to indicate the order).

[image]

6. Remove the unnecessary fields.

[image]

Hope it helps!